# Could not load main class in jar created by Netbeans using Maven

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, jar, package

I created a Maven Java Application project. I have defined following tags in the pom file,

```
<build>
<plugins>
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
<configuration>
  <archive>
    <manifest>
      <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
      <mainClass>com.it.rng.dataservice.DataService</mainClass>
    </manifest>
  </archive>
</configuration>
</plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
```

When I build the project in NetBeans, The jar is created in the target folder as expected. But when I try to run that jar using,

```
java -jar application.jar
```

i get the following error,

> Error: Could not find or load main class com.it.rng.dataservice.DataService

I have checked the jar's contents and the class files are inside the directory as follows,

> application.jar->com->it->rng->dataservice->DataService.class

I am not sure what is wrong here. Please let me know if I am missing anything.

Edit:
Also the application runs fine if I use the 'Run' command in the IDE.

Comment: Is the Mainclass entry added to MANIFEST file?

Comment: @Jens The error indicates that there is a main class entry, otherwise it wouldn't have known to try to start `com.it.rng.dataservice.DataService`

Comment: It was not initially, I dont know why then I added it manually.